# Pointers confusion in Go

Tags: pointers, go

I am having a hard time understanding the below code, I have it working but still don't understand it.
It would really helpful if someone can demystify it

**In below code Flags name is not updated to "Changed"**

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Command struct {
   Name  string
   Flags []Flag
}

type Flag struct {
   Name      string
   Shorthand string
}

func getCommand() *Command {
   return &Command{Name: "Hello", Flags: []Flag{{"version", "v"}}}
}

func change(cmd *Command) {
   for _, flg := range cmd.Flags {
       flg.Name = "Changed"
   }

}

func main() {
   cmd := getCommand()
   change(cmd)
   fmt.Println(cmd.Flags[0])

}
```

Correct code. Flags Name is changed to "Changed"

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Command struct {
    Name  string
    Flags []*Flag
}

type Flag struct {
    Name      string
    Shorthand string
}

func getCommand() *Command {
    return &Command{Name: "Hello", Flags: []*Flag{{"version", "v"}}}
}

func change(cmd *Command) {
    for _, flg := range cmd.Flags {
        flg.Name = "Changed"
    }

}

func main() {
    cmd := getCommand()
    change(cmd)
    fmt.Println(cmd.Flags[0])

}
```

I am sure, my confusion might be trivial, but it has wasted my couple of hours

Comment: When you range over a slice, the iteration variable (`flg` in this case) is assigned a *copy* of the element from the slice. Modifying the copy won't modify the original in the slice. When you use pointers, same copying is happening, but this time, it's the copying of the pointer, and both the original pointer and the copied pointer point to the same value, and any modifications done to the value, from any of the pointers or directly, will be "visible" to any and all pointers that point to the value.

Answer (score 1):

In your first version, when you do this:

```
for _, flg := range cmd.Flags {
    flg.Name = "Changed"
}
```

`flg` is a local variable of type `Flag`.  On each iteration of the `for` loop, `range` sets `flg` to a copy of the next item in `cmd.Flags`.  So when you change that, nothing changes outside that loop.

In your second version, when you do that loop, `flg` is a local variable of type `*Flag`, so when range sets it to a copy of the next item in `cmd.Flags`, `flg` is pointing to the data you are trying to mutate, and mutating it actually changes that data.

Comment: So if i use for loop rather than range I should be able to mutate without in the version of the code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
for _, flg := range cmd.Flags {
        flg.Name = "Changed"
    }
```

This part is the exact culprit. The first value returned by range is the index(which is ignored here), the second value is a **copy** of the actual data. When you are using it inside the loop(flg.Name=...), You are assigning the value to Name filed of the copy. You may do this:

```
for index, _ := range cmd.Flags {
        cmd.Flags[index].Name = "Changed"
    }
```

In the second case, you are assigning to Name field of a **copy of reference(or memory address)** to the Flag, so the value at that memory address get changed.

Comment: Correct: I think it was a wrong use of loop in my code. Still learning  go :)